# Flow: why does it complain about string being null / undefined?

Tags: flowtype

I am still try to grasp how Flow works, anyone could explain me why this simple example is throwing an error?

```
function say(text: string) {
  console.log(text);
}

say('Hello World!'); // This is alright

const text: ?string = 'Hello World!';
say(text); // Error:(219, 5) Cannot call `say` with `text` bound to `text` because null or undefined [1] is incompatible with string [2].
```

I know, the text variable can be null, but by the time I call say(text) it is clearly not null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flow does not keep track of what you have assigned to what.  It only tracks the types of the variables.  And you are trying to pass type `?string` to `string`, which isn't a valid assignment since it could be `null`. You know its not null but flow doesn't because it's not actually executing your code.

It's hard to give you good advice for a workaround because `const text: ?string = 'Hello World!';` is a very contrived example, but you can use a [refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) to only call `say` if `text` has been tested for a non-null value.

```
const text: ?string = 'Hello World!';
if (text) {
  say(text);
}
```

---

The only time flow does track what you assign is on variable initialization for implicit typings. But this simply assigns the type of the right hand expression as the type of the variable.

```
let a: ?string = 'foo'
let b = a; // flow infers the type of b as ?string
```